# Get Error when try to extract value for point from set of rasters

Tags: python

Get Error " list indices must be integers, not tuple" when try to extract value for point from set of rasters:

```
def defineIndexAllPoints(inputPoints, inputRaster, indexName):
    #Define file of points:    
    desc = arcpy.Describe(inputPoints)
    shapefieldname = desc.ShapeFieldName*

    #Define set of rasters"
    rstArray  = [arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(arcpy.Describe(ras).catalogPath) for ras in arcpy.ListRasters()] 

    #This code was help from this  web site
    ulx = desc.Extent.XMin
    uly = desc.Extent.YMax

    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(infc,["SHAPE@", indexName]) as uc: #"value - will be different Indexes for  different  Data Set Images:"
        for row in uc:
            pnt = row[0].projectAs(sr)
    #assuming every point falls to the left and below uperleft corner
            deltaX = pnt.centroid.X - ulx
            deltaY = uly- pnt.centroid.Y
            arow = int(deltaY/rastr.meanCellHeight)
            acol = int(deltaX/rastr.meanCellWidth)
            row[1] = rstArray[arow,acol]
            uc.updateRow(row)

env.workspace = r"C:\Users\1_fire_RdNBR" 
inputPoints = r"C:\Users\select1.shp"     

defineIndexAllPoints(inputPoints, env.workspace, "dNBR_1")
```

I think something wrong with inputRaster - but rstArray - just ask about .catalogPath.
 how to fix it?

I just want to ask  this function     convert list of rasters in   1  Numpy array or   Not?

Comment: This is a  set of rasters  (list of rasters in folder).  I hope   rstArray   - was right (has to be 1 Numpy Array  from set of rasters???).

Comment: Please post a MCVE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: *"list indices must be integers, not tuple"* You're indirectly asking the community to look through the code to find the lists, determine *which* list might be causing the issue, ignore the possibility that the list in question might be somewhere else which we can't know because there are no line numbers, etc. I'm sure your intentions are good but you're making it harder than it has to be (that's what she said). Just **post the entire traceback**. That being said, `row[1] = rstArray[arow,acol]` <-- isn't this a tuple being passed to a list? Should your lists be numpy arrays instead?

Comment: yes, I see it just a list rasters.

Comment: Is not  function < rstArray  = [arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(arcpy.Describe(ras).catalogPath) for ras in arcpy.ListRasters()] >   convert List of rasters   to Numpy Array?